# Redirecting the customer to page after some delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written this JavaScript code which when executed on button click displays a message and redirects the user to another page. I want the user to actually see the message before he is redirected to new page. I put 1000ms as timer but that doesn't seems to work, i tried searching  the internet but I didn't find suitable answer. the script is stored in separate js file.Below is script

```
$('#cspwd_submit').click(function(event){

         event.preventDefault();

        $.post('../../controller/usermgmt/resetpwd.php',$('#reset_password').serialize(),function(resp)
        {
            if (resp['status'] == true)
            {   
                var htm = '<br><div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"></button><strong>Success!!!</strong>'+resp['msg'];
                htm += '</div>';
                //$("#error-msg").html(msg);
                //location.href = "sys_admin.php";
                location.href = "../index.php",1000;

                $("#error-msg1").html(htm);
                $("#error-msg1").show();
            }
            else
            {
                var htm = '<br><div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"></button><strong>Error!</strong>    ';
                $.each(resp['msg'],function(index,val){
                    htm += val+" <br>";
                    });
                htm += '</div>';
                $("#error-msg1").html(htm);
                $("#error-msg1").show();    
                $(this).prop('disabled',false);
            }
        },'json');
    });
```

Can someone help me in understanding where i am going wrong?

Comment: Search the webs, or stack overflow, for "javascript, setTimeout"

Comment: Put your `location.href = "../index.php",1000;` inside timeout. It should not even work like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work. It is like:

```
location.href = "../index.php";
1000;
```

Obviously the `1000;` expression does not nothing.

Use setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function() { location.href = "../index.php"; }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

where `location.href = "../index.php",1000;`

`setTimeout(function() { window.location = "../index.php" }, 1000);`

I think that this is correct but not tested, but that is the gist of what your looking for.

hope it helps :)